# How can I change login info without needing to restart?

Tags: pewdiepie-tuber-simulator

How do I change my login info from Google play over to game center with out having to start over? I keep looking through other websites but none if the problems state the same probably I'm having.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, there is no such way to change accounts without restarting, as your progress is tied to your account.